# Fast per-column summation. Possible?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, math, sum

Please look at this picture:

[image]

Is it possible to find per-column sum for all columns faster than in O(n^2)?

Firstly I thought it's possible to make it n * log(n), if we regroup summation like this (to sum 2 rows at time, then remaining 2 rows, and then remaining 2 rows...):

[image]

But then I counted the number of pluses and it came out to be equal in both cases - 7 = 7 from both pictures.

So is it possible to compose such a sum in n * log(n) time, or I have fooled myself (I know there are FHT or FFT like transforms, so that might be the case)?

Comment: What's n?  I mean to me `n = 8` and `m = 10` and you have `(n-1)*m` pluses

Comment: @hroptatyr: Throught I have drawn different n and m, I used n^2 and n*log(n) just for simplicity. But we may assume n = m = 8 for example - there will be no  much difference.

Comment: @hroptatyr: n is number of rows. m - number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, our input size is `O(n^2)`, so our algorithm can not be faster than that (because we are using all the input values).

This is assuming that `n` is the amount of rows, that the matrix is square (giving `n^2`) and there is no special relation between the elements.

Comment: @amit: Does it changes something if we know that each array represents sampled sinusoid? (But their sum is not periodical waveform, so we can't use FFT)

Comment: @Vadim: apart from that every value is in the range 0-1, pretty much nothing.

Answer (score 2):

No.  You need to read (at least) n^2 items from memory, which takes (at least) O(n^2) time.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1. Assuming n is the number of columns (or number of rows).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be done better then `O(n^2)` unless you have more knowledge on the matrix.

You need to read each element in the matrix to get the correct sum for each column, so you get a lower bound of `Omega(n^2)`

Also, note that your idea is `O(n^2)`, because even at the first iteration, you summaize have `n * (n/2)` sum ops, which is `O(n^2)`